# wine not found for python in kali

Tags: python, linux, wine, kali-linux

When running a python script in Linux its throwing an error,

```
wine: cannot find '/root/.wine/drive_c/Python27/Scripts/pyinstaller.exe'
```

And installing wine from also fails. 
OS: Kali Linux 2020
Python-version: 3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install wine. We’ll first enable maltiarch, then update the system and finally install wine.

Follow the commands

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install wine:i386
sudo apt-get install wine-bin:i386
```

And that's all. 
Verify by running `wine --version` .